# closure compiler - keep unused functions and don't rename the undefined

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure-compiler

So closure compiler is great but exporting functions and defining externs seems to be too much manual work. **Is there a way to tell the compiler that it should not remove any functions and should not rename any undefined functions?**

I have 2 major reasons behind this:

1. If a function or property is not defined in the scope of the javascript document, then it's probably defined in an external file. Therefore, I wouldn't like these to be renamed.
2. If the function is defined in a given scope but isn't being called within the same scope, then it's probably being called in some external code. Therefore, I would like to keep this function in the file without renaming it.

This way, we could simply compile javascript files without worrying about external libraries and exporting functions that are called from html pages.

Comment: You need to read up on "externs" and "exporting a function".

Answer (score 1):

It very much sounds like you should run the compiler with the optimization level of SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS. Don't be fooled by the name, as it still fully compiles your code. The main difference is that SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATION will not rename or eliminate dead code in the global scope. This means the requirements of externs and exports are no longer present.

Comment: This is true, but I would like to use the advanced_optimization to rename my defined functions. Of course, this can be done manually but it would be have been great if the closure compiler allowed for this.

Comment: If you wrap your code in an immediately-executed anonymous function, it will no longer be in the global scope. The compiler will be able to rename the local functions using SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS. However, since your code is wrapped, you will now have to export your symbols which need to be exposed to the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, I run the closure compiler on a complete script that is the concatenation of all the scripts of my application. So this is a two-step process :

1 - concatenate all

2 - run the closure compiler

Additionally, you may want (as I often do, due to problems with jquery before v1.8) to run the compiler with compilationLevel="simple".

Concatenation is very important as in general the slowness isn't related to the total size but mainly to the number of requests.

EDIT : of course you have to automate all this. I can provide you an ant task definition if you use ant.